# How to select/unselect select options with checkboxes with JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have almost no knowledge of JavaScript or jQuery.

I need to select/unselect an option in a `<select>` where multiple options can be selected when a checkbox or button is clicked.

The checkbox needs to select/unselect the option with the same value.
My idea was something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $('#entry-select');
  var checkboxes = $('.entrycheckbox');

  checkboxes.click(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var value = element.val();
    input.val(value);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="entrycheckbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="entrycheckbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="entrycheckbox" value="3">
<form action="">
  <select name="entries" id="entry-select" multiple>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
    <option value="3">Option3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

This only selects the option with the value of the last clicked checkbox, not which ones are checked, and it unselects every other option.

Comment: use `checked` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only give `val()` the value of the checkbox which was selected last. To make this work as you require you need to build an array of all selected checkboxes and provide that to `val()` instead.

To achieve this you can use `filter()` to get the selected checkboxes, then `map()` to build the array:

```
input.val(checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, el) => el.value));
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input = $('#entry-select');
  var $checkboxes = $('.entrycheckbox');

  $checkboxes.click(function() {
    $input.val($checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, el) => el.value));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="entrycheckbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="entrycheckbox" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="entrycheckbox" value="3">
<form action="">
  <select name="entries" id="entry-select" multiple>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
    <option value="2">Option2</option>
    <option value="3">Option3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

You may also want to consider adding `readonly` to the `select` if you don't want the user to change the selected `option` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.entrycheckbox').click(function(){

                $(":entrycheckbox").each(function(){
                    if($(this).val()==1){     
                    $(this).attr("checked","checked");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: something like this you have to check each value to ensure the fault in your code you're checking only last value so you're getting last value